# Does Information Expert pattern contradict Service Layer Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns, grasp

While reading about GRASP patterns I stopped at Information Expert, which states that behavior on classes state should be within that same class. But that is a complete opposite with Service Layer pattern which I used for years. Services have behavior for Domain objects' state.
Which confuses me

I would be grateful for a thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

Information expert is about objects that contain data (aggregates, entities, value objects) and the operation mostly depends on the data they have.

A trivial example: imagine you have a `Customer` class and you want to produce the customer full name. Rather than having a class that does:

```
   class SomethingService {
     String customerFullName(Customer customer) {
       return "${customer.firstName()} ${customer.lastName()}";
     }
   }
```

A much better approach is to have that method in the customer class itself, as the customer class has all the data required. In a way, this is the opposite of the [Feature Envy Antipattern](https://refactoring.guru/smells/feature-envy).

About the service layer, this could be seen as [Pure Fabrication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Pure_fabrication) in GRASP terms. With the caveat that in things like DDD there are Application Services (very similar as a Facade from the *Gang of Four book* or a Port in *Ports and Adapters Architecture*) and Domain Services (internal services to the domain which don't really fit in any other class). The way I think about the latter is that if I need to add some functionality but there's no clear place where that should go, it ends up in a new domain service. I hope this is clear!